# height:auto attribute gets messed up when using different positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a module for a website. This module will include a heading, text, and an image. I would like the webmaster to be able to insert as many of these modules as he likes into a page and ideally he should be able to type as much as he wants in a module and have it auto adjust to the proper height.

**Here's the problem:**

I can't seem to get the height of the entire module called "myModlue" (the red box that hold the heading, image and text) to be auto height, and also have "moduleBody" set to auto height with out the two divs conflicting. In order to have "mymodule" recognize the content inside so that the height auto adjusts, I need to set the positioning to absolute. At this point "mymodule" is containing everything like it should, but "moduleBody" is not....moduleBody is collapsed and will not acknowledge the elements inside unless I set it's position to absolute as well. When I do this "moduleBody" does adjust in height, but now "myModule" no longer includes "moduleBody" in the height, it only sees "moduleHeader" (which is not set to position:absolute;) How can I make both "myModule" and "moduleBody" auto height and have everything work correctly?

FYI: the styles are all embedded directly into the html, my complete version will absolutely not look this way, I've only done this because I want to see how things look quickly as I'm testing. The weird colors are for testing purposes too.

Thanks to anyone who helps,
Lindsay :)

---

### myModule.html

```
<div id= "myModule"style="height:auto; width: 1000px;  position:absolute; background-color:red;" >

        <div id= "moduleHeader" style = "width:100%; height:auto; background-color:yellow; ">
            <p style="text-align:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:22px; font-size:30px; color:#191970; margin-left:20px;">Who We Are 
            <span><b style="color:#999; font-size:20px;">Learn more about Trinity</b></span></p>
        </div>

        <div id= "moduleBody" style="background-color:#0E1031; width:800px; height:auto; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding:40px;border:thick solid #1B1851;  border-radius: 15px; position:absolute;">
            <p style=" text-align:justify; height:150px; width:500px;   font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; line-height:150%; float:left; color:white; ">
            The United Church of Christ acknowledges as its sole head, Jesus Christ, Son of God and Savior. 
            It acknowledges as kindred in Christ all who share in this confession. It looks to the Word of 
            God in the Scriptures, and to the presence and power of the Holy Spirit, to prosper its creative 
            and redemptive work in the world. It claims as its own the faith of the historic Church expressed 
            in the ancient creeds and reclaimed in the basic insights of the Protestant Reformers. It affirms 
            the responsibility of the Church in each generation to make this faith its own in reality of worship, 
            in honesty of thought and expression, and in purity of heart before God. In accordance with the teaching 
            of our Lord and the practice prevailing among evangelical Christians, it recognizes two sacraments: 
            Baptism and the Lords Supper or Holy Communion.
            </p>        
            <div id="mod_Image" style="height:250px; width:200px;margin-left:40px; float:left; border:thick solid white;"><img src="churchImg.jpg" style="height:100%; width:100%; "/></div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `overflow: auto;` on the two divs giving you trouble. This is an issue with elements containing floated elements - they collapse in on themselves because their contents have been removed from the normal content flow (ie. they have nothing to tell them how tall they should be).

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for this answer. overflow: auto worked to an extent...but now the whole thing is packed into a smaller box (the size of the header) with a scroll bar. I'll have to play around unless you now how to fix this problem too.

Comment: It's easier to address specific problems you encounter if you provide a clear example of it (preferably on a website like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), with the HTML and CSS separated), and explaining what you've tried. I know you said you embedded styles just for testing, but it's much easier to debug and figure out issues if they're kept out of the markup.

Comment: I may have misunderstood you, but now after playing with the overflow attribute I got it to work just right. "MyModule" is set to absolute, "moduleBody" and "moduleHeader" are set to overflow: auto, and it all works! I can't thank you enough, this was driving my crazy!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are seeing is due to elements being floated, which means that they have been removed from normal flow and will **not** be used by the browser when calculating height of containing elements. There are plenty of blog posts out there about CSS `float`, so I'll only link one for [background reading](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/).

There are many ways to fix this for example on the quirksmode blog - [Clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html). The most famous is known as the "clear fix", an example of which can be found [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) and also below:

```
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

So applying to your (cleaned up) *HTML* as seen in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4zRwA/) or below@

```
<div id= "myModule">
    <div id="moduleHeader">
        <p>Who We Are <span><b style="color:#999; font-size:20px;">Learn more about Trinity</b></span></p>
    </div>
    <div id= "moduleBody" class="cf">
        <p>The United Church of Christ acknowledges as its sole head, Jesus Christ, Son of God and Savior. It acknowledges as kindred in Christ all who share in this confession. It looks to the Word of God in the Scriptures, and to the presence and power of the Holy Spirit, to prosper its creative and redemptive work in the world. It claims as its own the faith of the historic Church expressed in the ancient creeds and reclaimed in the basic insights of the Protestant Reformers. It affirms the responsibility of the Church in each generation to make this faith its own in reality of worship, in honesty of thought and expression, and in purity of heart before God. In accordance with the teaching of our Lord and the practice prevailing among evangelical Christians, it recognizes two sacraments: Baptism and the Lords Supper or Holy Communion.</p>
        <div id="mod_Image"><img src="churchImg.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

*CSS*

```
#myModule {
    width:1000px;
    background-color:red;
}

#moduleHeader {
    background-color:yellow;
}

#moduleHeader p {
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:22px;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#191970;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#moduleBody {
    background-color:#0E1031;
    width:800px;
    padding:40px;border:thick solid #1B1851; 
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#moduleBody p {
    text-align:justify;
    height:150px;
    width:500px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:150%;
    float:left;
    color:white; 
}

#mod_Image {
    height:250px;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:40px;
    float:left;
    border:thick solid white;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Note that you do not need to be specifying any of `height:auto`, `position:absolute`, `width:100%` as these are the defaults for the elements where you had them applied to.

An alternative approach is to remove the "clear fix" class and `float:left` and use `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:top;` instead as in [**this alternate demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4zRwA/2/).